# TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float do not understand why this is happening

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, parsing

all,

i get the above error as in title, but i am unsure as to why this is happening. my `row['date']` values look like : `2012-10-04T00:00:00` . when i debug this it of 'str' type.

the output of row['date'] is: 2016-06-22T00:00:00
2016-06-23T00:00:00
2016-06-23T00:00:00
2016-06-25T00:00:00
2016-06-29T00:00:00
2016-06-30T00:00:00
2016-06-30T00:00:00
2016-07-06T00:00:00
2016-07-07T00:00:00
2016-07-07T00:00:00

```
for row in data['date_of_incorporation']:
    new_date = datetime.strptime(row, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

new_date then becomes a datetime object.

i need it in above format because i then would like to extract year and month:

```
year = new_date.year
month = new_date.month
```

but if it is already in str, i don't get why i am getting the error:

```
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not float
```

Comment: it is of type object

Comment: What Is the output of `type(row['date'])`?

Comment: Please clarify: you tagged your question `pandas`, so is `data` a DataFrame?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a `pandas` DataFrame, you probably want to convert to datetime. after that you can use the `dt` accessor to get year and month.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'date_of_incorporation': ['2012-10-04T00:00:00']})

data['date_of_incorporation'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date_of_incorporation'])

data['date_of_incorporation'].dt.year
# 0    2012
# Name: date_of_incorporation, dtype: int64

data['date_of_incorporation'].dt.month
# 0    10
# Name: date_of_incorporation, dtype: int64
```

...or generate a string output with a certain format:

```
data['date_of_incorporation'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
# 0    2012-10
# Name: date_of_incorporation, dtype: object
```